# VBA Function for Correlation matrices WITHOUT invoking any worksheetFunction

Tags: vba, matrix, covariance

i'm looking for a way to calculate a correlation matrix of a bunch ob observations. My trials are so far this:

```
Function VarCovar(Rng As range) As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim numcols As Integer

numcols = Rng.Columns.Count
Dim matrix() As Double
ReDim matrix(numcols - 1, numcols - 1)
For i = 1 To numcols
    For j = 1 To numcols
        matrix(i - 1, j - 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Covar(Rng.Columns(i), Rng.Columns(j))
    Next j
Next i

VarCovar = matrix

End Function
```

However, i'd like to aviod this `Application.WorksheetFunction.Covar` part and write it explicitly in the code. Would anyone mind to help me?
Thanks a lot
Best regards
Thomas

Comment: You need to provide the equations you will use to calculate covar and then the code you have tried which implements those equations.  You might also provide the justification for not using the Worksheet function.  You need to do this to prove that we are not doing your homework/coursework assignment for you.

Comment: @freeflow Thanks for your comment (and probably the downvote). To address your suspicion: no, its not for my homework (i'm already 42 :-D). The reason why i asked was that i had an older version of Excel on my PC (2003), where i have several limitations wrt MMULT, MINV etc. I suspected that such restrictions in general exist for the Correlation_S etc. functions. I have a dataset of roughly 6400 observations, which are difficult to handle. However, i have a newer version of excel on my laptop where this code above works fine. I don't have the possibility to close the question, would you mind?